# How to programmatically determine the minimum set of files required to import a given Python module?

Tags: python, macos, python-import, appkit, pyobjc

I'm working on a Python3 script that uses [pyobjc](https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc/) to access the macOS clipboard via `NSPasteboard`. To do this, it requires the following import:

```py
from AppKit import NSPasteboard
```

In order to keep my distribution to a minimum size (the full pyobjc 9.2 package is **30MB**), I wanted to find out the smallest set of files needed in order to allow this import to succeed. Through trial-and-error (using a REPL and attempting to import `NSPasteboard`, looking at the stack trace errors and adding in missing modules one by one), I determined this to be:

```
./lib
├── AppKit
├── CoreFoundation
├── Foundation
├── objc
└── PyObjCTools
```

This slimmed set is only **7MB** by comparison.

**My question is**: is there a more pragmatic way to determine this? Using [importlib](https://importlib-metadata.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#package-distributions) or something similar?

Comment: It can't be done for all cases as imports can e. g. be part of an if-block where the value of the condition can't be calculated beforehand.

Comment: On Linux, `strace python prog.py` displays the name of each file opened. Maybe there is something similar for macOS.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting question and for sharing your approach! I guess package file size is something I haven't thought about in a while, but it has implications on portability. Edit: are you moving packages out from ./lib to see if the script continues to work?

Answer (score 0):

These commands give minimum imports :

```
python -v -c "from AppKit import NSPasteboard" |&\
    perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if (/^import '"'"'([^'"'"'.]+)/)' | sort -u
```

*Update*

This script gets the minimum required:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dir=/tmp/lib
python3 -m pip install --isolated --target=$dir pyobjc
for c in $(python -v -c "from AppKit import NSPasteboard" 2>&1 |
    perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if (/^import '"'"'([^'"'"'.]+)/)' | sort -u); do
    test -d $dir/$c && echo $c
done
```

Comment: That's interesting @Philippe but it prints 98 lines of output, many of those modules are Python3 builtins. Do you know how to get it to output only the necessary additional modules as shown in my OP? (`AppKit`, `CoreFoundation`, `Foundation`, `objc` and `PyObjCTools`)

Comment: How did you find `the full pyobjc 9.2 package is 30MB` ? and how did you install pyobjc ?

Comment: I installed pyobjc locally to my program's directory using `python3 -m pip install --isolated --target=./lib pyobjc` and as for the size, I just used "get info" in Finder on the resulting `lib` folder.